# Why can't I use key path syntax in a map statement?

Tags: swift, swift-keypath

Imagine I have a struct AStruct:

```
struct AStruct {
    let name: String
    let value: Int
}
```

And imagine I have an array of `AStruct`s:

```
let array: [AStruct] = [
AStruct(name: "John", value: 1),
    AStruct(name: "Bob", value: 23),
    AStruct(name: "Carol", value: 17),
    AStruct(name: "Ted", value: 9),
    AStruct(name: "Alice", value: 13),
    AStruct(name: "Digby", value: 4)
]
```

Now imagine I want to use a `map()` to create an array of integers out of my array of `AStruct`s.

This code works:

```
let values = array.map { $0.value }
```

But if I try to use Swift key path syntax I get errors no matter what I try. Example:

```
let values = array.map { \.value }
```

I get an error:

> Cannot infer key path type from context; consider explicitly specifying a root type.

So how do I that?

I can get it to work if I give the input a name and type:

```
let values = array.map { (aVal: AStruct) -> Int in
    return aVal.value
}
```

But that is distinctly **not** key path syntax.

Comment: You pass the key path as the parameter instead of a closure: `let values = array.map(\.value)`.

Comment: Ok, that works, but why doesn't it work with closure syntax? (This is a simplified case to illustrate the problem. It isn't always as simple as passing a key path in to `map()`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SE-0249: Key Path Expressions as Functions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md) is the relevant Swift Evolution proposal for this feature, and from that proposal:

> As implemented in apple/swift#19448, occurrences of `\Root.value` are implicitly converted to key path applications of `{ $0[keyPath: \Root.value] }` wherever `(Root) -> Value` functions are expected. For example:
>
> ```
> users.map(\.email)
> ```
>
> Is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> users.map { $0[keyPath: \User.email] }
> ```

<snip>

> When inferring the type of a key path literal expression like `\Root.value`, the type checker will prefer `KeyPath<Root, Value>` or one of its subtypes, but will also allow `(Root) -> Value`. If it chooses `(Root) -> Value`, the compiler will generate a closure with semantics equivalent to capturing the key path and applying it to the Root argument. For example:
>
> ```
> // You write this:
> let f: (User) -> String = \User.email
>
> // The compiler generates something like this:
> let f: (User) -> String = { kp in { root in root[keyPath: kp] } }(\User.email)
> ```

In other words: the compiler recognizes a keypath expression *when passed in as a direct argument* to where a function is expected, and injects a conversion from the keypath to a generated closure. When you write

```swift
array.map { \.value }
```

you are passing in a closure whose body *evaluates* to a key path, and because the key path is then seemingly arbitrary to the compiler here (e.g., it has no context for what type `\.value` is rooted off of), you get the error.

---

Also important to note is that:

> The implementation is limited to key path literal expressions (for now), which means the following is not allowed:
>
> ```
> let kp = \User.email // KeyPath<User, String>
> users.map(kp)
> ```

I don't recall whether this restriction has been lifted at this point, but if you find yourself in a situation where you have a keypath you need to apply but automatic conversion won't work, you'll need to pass the keypath into a closure manually, and key off of that keypath directly.

Comment: It seems that the restriction about *literal* key path expressions has not been lifted as of Xcode 14.

Answer (score 3):

[SE-0249](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md) allows for key paths to be treated as closures. `map` takes an "`(Element) throws -> T`"—for example, in your case, this one:

```swift
{ $0.value } as (AStruct) -> _
```

But a key path ***is not a closure***. So you can't treat it as one…

```swift
array.map { (\.value)($0) }
```

…unless you explicitly type it:

```swift
array.map { (\.value as (_) -> _)($0) }
```

But you would never do that. The original

```swift
array.map { $0.value }
```

syntax is better. However, the most common way to cast the key path to a closure is better-looking.

```swift
array.map(\.value)
```

[Also, key paths currently have a feature related to implicitly-opened existentials that functions do not.](https://forums.swift.org/t/inconsistent-ergonomics-with-implicitly-opened-existentials-key-path-closures-vs-functions/)