# Swift difference between list.map(\.property) and list.map { $0.property }

Tags: swift

I've just noticed that both return the same result but what is this notation:

```
list.map(\.property)
```

compared to the usual

```
list.map { $0.property }
```

I've noticed that `\.` is used in many swiftUI example but this code also works outside of any SwiftUI code. I wonder where does this syntax `\.` come from.

Comment: It is explained in the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/72652593/1187415. See also https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md

Comment: In short, `\.property` is a “key path expression” and that can be used as a closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` denotes a [key path](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID563), which can be of one of the [key path types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/key-path-expressions). `\.property` is short for `\SomeType.property`, where `property` is a property of `SomeType`. `SomeType` is inferred from the context of the `map` call.

Since [SE-0249](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md) was implemented, key path literal expressions can now be used where a function type is expected. The [original pitch](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-keypath-based-map-flatmap-filter/6266/45) is also very interesting to read.

> occurrences of `\Root.value` are implicitly converted to key path
> applications of `{ $0[keyPath: \Root.value] }` wherever `(Root) -> Value` functions are expected. For example:
>
> ```
> users.map(\.email)
> ```
>
> Is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> users.map { $0[keyPath: \User.email] }
> ```

In your case, assuming `property` is of type `AnotherType`, `map` would have expected a `(SomeType) -> AnotherType` function as its parameter, but you have used the key path `\.property` instead. This is the same as passing the closure `{ $0.property }` and also  `{ $0[keyPath: \SomeType.property] }`.

You can also pass longer key paths, like `\.property1.property2.property3`, too. See [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID563) for more details on the syntax.

Checking on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org) with some very simple examples, using key paths vs not using them seem to compile to the same assembly when using the `-O` flag.